# How to analyse the test result of ltp testcases

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, linux-mint

I have runned the testcases for ltp, But i don't know how to analyse the results.So please share me the document that i can check whether the testcase has failed or passed.I am running ltp few week onwords without knowledge,So could you please give some berif about this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you started the testrun with runltp shell script that gets installed into the /opt/ltp/ directory. In that case the results are stored in the /opt/ltp/output/*.failed and /opt/ltp/results/*.log. The failed file contains list of failed test cases and the log file contains list of executed test cases. You can customize which test cases are executed and where are results stored via runltp script parameters (see runltp -h for more).

Then there is a Open Posix Testsuite that is not ported to the LTP execution framework and could be started with 'make test' in the testcases/open_posix_testsuite/ directory in the LTP source tree. The results are logged into logfile.foo-test files. There may be a few known failures, feel free to consult the results on the LTP mailing list.

And if anything is not clear do not hesitate to ask on LTP mailing list at ltp-list@lists.sourceforge.net.